# If $F$ is closed then $A = \{a\in\mathbb{R}^{n}: \text{there exists}\quad x \in F\quad\text{with}\quad ||x - a|| = \delta\}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove the next:

Let $F\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a closed set and $\delta>0.$ Show that A is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ if $$A = \{a\in\mathbb{R}^{n}: \text{there exists}\quad x \in F\quad\text{with}\quad ||x - a|| = \delta\}.$$

I was attempting to prove that each convergent sequence on $A$ must have its limit in $A$: If $(a_{m})_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\subset A$ such that $a_{m}\rightarrow a,$ then for each $m$ we have there exists $x_{m}\in F$ with property $||a_{m} - x_{m}|| = \delta.$ So I was trying to prove that the sequence $(x_{m})_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ must be convergent in $F$ to some $x$ to utilize closedness of $F$ and have the desired property but I do not know how to do this.

Other attempt was writting A as a union of circumferences of closed balls with center in each point of $F$ and trying to prove the limit of a sequence must be in such union but seems not a good way...

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Look more closely, if your $a_m$ converges, your $x_n$ are in a bounded and closed set... what can you tell about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that a subset of $(\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|)$ is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277210/show-that-a-subset-of-mathbb-rn-cdot-is-closed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sequence $(a_m)$ converges, hence it is bounded. Since $\|a_m - x_m\| = \delta$, the set of $x_m$'s is also bounded, thus it lives in the intersection of $F$ (a closed set) and a closed ball, thus in a compact space (finite dimension).
You can extract $x_m$ to make it converge to $x \in F$ and you have
$$\|a - x\| = \| a - a_{\varphi(n)} + a_{\varphi(n)} - x_{\varphi(n)} + x_{\varphi(n)} - x \|$$
which has the same limit as $\|a_{\varphi(n)} - x_{\varphi(n)} \| = \delta$ so
$$\|a-x\| = \delta$$
thus $a \in A$ which means that $A$ is closed!

Comment: Thanks. The key was to look at F and the intersection of a closed ball...